# File sometimes got uploaded successfully & sometimes it disappears from the /tmp directory

Tags: php, nginx, ubuntu-14.04, laravel-5

I am running a **Laravel 5.2** application with **PHP 5.5** and nginx on Ubuntu 14.04.

Sometimes it got uploaded successfully without any error, also sometimes out of nowhere it produces this error.

[image: Image of the Exception thrown by Laravel]

I don't know what the problem is or what is happening. I can't reproduce the error every time. It just happens randomly!

---

Here is what I've tried (already configured):

php.ini:

```
post_max_size: 20M
upload_max_filesize: 20M
memory_limit: -1
max_execution_time: 60
max_input_time: 60
```

nginx configuration:

```
client_max_body_size 100m;
```

Comment: Note that >= 5.5.9 is required for Laravel 5.2

Comment: @Michael Yea i am using 5.5.9 exactly, also why does it get through and uploaded successfully sometimes & the other times it throws this exception just randomly !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted my question on Laracasts Forums [here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/file-sometimes-got-uploaded-successfully-sometimes-it-disappears-from-the-tmp-directory) & that is what i got:

It got removed in the 5.2.14 release, here is the [commits](https://github.com/laravel/framework/commits/5.2/src/Illuminate/Http/UploadedFile.php) of `UploadedFile` Class.

Answer (score 0):

i don't know how it happen..!!you can try below code and may be help you..!

```
$bannerimage = $req->file('uploadusers');
                    if($bannerimage!='') 
                    {   
                        $destination = 'public/uploadimage/';
                        $newname = str_random(5);
                        $ext = $bannerimage->getClientOriginalExtension();
                        $filename = $newname.'-original.'.$ext;
                        $newFilename = $newname.'.'.$ext;
                        if($bannerimage->move($destination, $filename))
                        {
                            copy($destination . $filename, $destination . $newFilename);
                        }
                    }
```